# What is the meaning of this expression used in Gamer?

Tags: dialogue, gamer

I just heard this line in Gamer (2009):

> Stop menstruating and just tell me whether we f***ing have it?

what does it really mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a figure of speech.  Basically it means to stop acting like a woman, get to the point.  It could be considered sexist or derogatory.  I don't know the context, but I'm guessing the subject was rambling on, complaining of something, or something similar.

Maybe this isn't the best answer, or shouldn't be considered an answer.  The question is more about language (OP must not be American, or English not native language maybe) and less about the actual movie in question.

Comment: No I think you got it. Sexist response inferring the talker was acting like a woman.